# Burninate request for 'fullpage'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

If we look at the [fullpag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullpage)e tag there are only 3 questions. 2 of them is actually [fullpage.js](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fullpage.js/info) and the other is still unknown to me. Do you think this is subject for burniation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was just one question left when I looked, and that just wanted retagging.

Now it's all gone, automatic tag-cleanup will reap the tag soon.